# French encoding hell somwhere in SQL, classic ASP, or Flash

Tags: sql-server, flash, character-encoding, asp-classic

I have a legacy classic ASP page (sad, I know) that holds a tinyMCE textarea to save french language html blocks. The data is saved to SQL server and is then presented to the user in a flash page.

I cannot get the encoding to work, namely french special chars. *ê* for instance is saved and shown as the char value *&ecirc*

The situation is this:

1) the tinyMCE shows *ê* in the visual panel and the char value *&ecirc* in the html source.

2) It sends to the sql "UPDATE N'*ê*' as it should, but this stores the char value *&ecirc* in the sql instead.

3) If I manually run in SQL the EXACT update command sent in SQL, as captured in profiler, it DOES save *ê* as it should.

4) Having manually saved in SQL the correct *ê* and loaded tinyMCE again, it loads from DB as *&ecirc*.

The ASP page is encoded as UTF-8. I've looked into TinyMCE language support but its only about the UI and makes no difference.

Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way? maybe it should all be saved as *&ecirc* and the issue is displaying it correctly in flash? (i.e. showing *&ecirc* as *ê* in flash)

I apologize that I have no idea about encoding, I'm sure it shows from the question.

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Does this help? - http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:entity_encoding

Comment: Thanks, John, I don't know how I missed that parameter. But now the saving to SQL is incorrect. "?" instead of special chars. I think I will put an iframe with an ASP.NET control for saving this html block, otherwise I won't see the end of this.

Comment: This is worth a read if you're working with Classic ASP in a language other than English. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx